# How to get Jquery dialog textbox value and <tr> cell value in dialog content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working with the library [contextmenu](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) options with table. When an option is selected with particular row, the row id should display in the dialogue content.In dialog content I have text box , the value of text box has to be passed to the method how can I do this? Below is what i have currently tried.

**Dialogue content**

```
<div id="dialogbox" >
  <p>Enter Driver Message for <span id="bus"></span> </p>
  <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg">
</div>
```

**Context Menu options**

```
$(function(){

    $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    /* trigger: 'hover',
    delay: 500, */
    autoHide: true,
    callback: function(key, options) {
        var message = "global: " + key;
        var busId = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text(); // table row value
        //document.getElementById("bus").innerHTML=busId;
        $('#bus').text(busId); //Here I am setting to diloug content 

    },
    items: {
        "DMsg": {
            name: "Send Driver Message", 
            icon: "edit", 
            // superseeds "global" callback
            callback: function(key, options) {



                var busId = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
                openDriverMsgDiloug(busId);
            }
        },


 function openDriverMsgDiloug(busId)
    {

        $('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
    }
```

**Dialogue Box**

```
 $("#dialogbox").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        title: "Driver Message",
        modal:true,
        buttons: [
                  {
                    text: "Send",
                    icons: {
                      primary: "ui-icon-heart"
                    },
                    click: function() {
                        var msg=   // have to get the value of textbox in diloug
                      sendToClient(busId,msg);                      
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                    }

                  },
                  {
                    text: "Close",
                    icons: {
                      primary: "ui-icon-heart"
                    },
                    click: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  }
                ]
    });
```

Comment: Are you using any external libraries .. is `contextmenu` an external library?

Comment: @gerdi i used this one for contextmenu http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the simple [`.val()` method](https://api.jquery.com/val/)?

```
var msg = $("#msg").val();
```